# Relationship between "Compact sets are closed" and separation axioms

Tags: general-topology

Let $CC=$"All compact sets are closed". What is the relationship between $CC$ and the separation axioms? I know $T2$ implies $CC$, and that $CC$ implies $T1$, is it equivalent to any of those though? or is it strictly weaker/stronger? If that's the case, is $CC$ plus a countability axiom equivalent to $T2$?

Comment: It's strictly between $T_1$ and $T_2$. Spaces with that property are known as KC-spaces or $T_B$-spaces. [This search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[general-topology]+KC-space) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[general-topology]+%24T_B%24-space) turn up a lot of posts here about such spaces. I don't know whether any of those addresses your last question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KC-spaces is a more common term. The notion was introduced in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316017?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and there it was already noted that $T_2$ implies KC, and KC implies $T_1$.

$\Bbb N$ in the cofinite topology is $T_1$ but not KC (all subspaces are compact, and only the finite ones and $\Bbb N$ are closed).

The Alexandroff compactification $\alpha(\Bbb Q)$ of the rationals is an example of a KC space that is not Hausdorff, so neither implication can be reversed, and we have a strict hierarchy.